# ListCollectionView moving items within groups up and down and update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, grouping, listcollectionview

I have a `CommandListBox` which has the `Itemsource` from a `ListCollectionView`.
I want to move items within groups up/down and update this in the UI. Right now I have to refresh the whole view to show the new sorting and then the expanders will be closed and the user has to select an expander again.

How can I move items within groups up and down in position in the UI?

```
 controls:CommandListBox Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                                     Visibility="{Binding IsSearchperformed, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                     Grid.Column="2"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}"
                                     ToolbarItems="{Binding ToolBarItems}"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle"
                               TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp"  IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Items[0].IsExpanded}" Margin="0,0,0,30" >
                                                <Expander.Header >
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="18" Padding="0" Margin="0"/>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                                    <Grid Margin="20 0 0 0" >
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                                            Content="{Binding Path=Items[0].DisplayRepresentation.Header}"/>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                                                        Grid.Row="1"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>

                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PropertySearchResult}">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DisplayRepresentation}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:CommandListBox>
```

---

```
public ListCollectionView SearchResults { 
    get => searchResults; 
    set => SetField(ref searchResults, value); 
}

public string SearchString {
    get => searchString;
    set {
        SetField(ref searchString, value);
        SearchResults.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to raise a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: i can't update the items themselves within a group because the groups in a listcollectionview are ReadonlyObservableCollections.

Comment: OK, but generally, if you change something and want WPF to update itself, you need to ensure that the bound object raises that event. Some classes (like `ObservableCollection`) will do it for you, otherwise you have to do it yourself. You don't have to do it in the property setter, you can call `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchResults))` from anywhere in the class.